# Swiffy transparent background not working with Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-swiffy

I am using the Swiffy conversion on a website. It works fine with FireFox but when it comes to Chrome it places a horrible black background around the animation. This is even after i set:

```
stage.setBackground(null);
```

I've also tried setting the CSS attributes of the Swiffy div container and its child elements but still no luck with Chrome? Surely it should work in Chrome. It is a Google product after all. Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply this css

               `background: none !important;`

Comment: I tried that but it still gives a black background around the animation in Chrome.

Comment: Ive added `background: none !important;` to the swiffycontainer div, child div and svg element. But still no luck in Chrome